# "Auth Fail" error when cloning GIT repository

Tags: eclipse, git, macos, egit

I am trying to clone a git repository to my **Mac** machine using **GitEye** software. This repository is present on a **Windows local server**. I am trying to clone the repository using **SSH** commands.

Recently, I started facing issue with the cloning operation. I am getting following error message:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: ssh://Admin@192.168.1.106:22/D://Repository/ABC: Auth fail
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ListRemoteOperation.run(ListRemoteOperation.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.SourceBranchPage$8.run(SourceBranchPage.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: ssh://Admin@192.168.1.106:22/D://Repository/ABC: Auth fail
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:198)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:117)
    ... 8 more
```

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

**EDIT:**

When I try to test the SSH connection from command line

```
Octanes-ABC:~ Octane_XYZ$ ssh Admin@192.168.1.106
Connection closed by 192.168.1.106 port 22
```

Comment: Did you create an SSH key and upload the public key?

Comment: I would suggest to not post your error as a screenshot. Instead use a `code` block. It is searchable, and can be quoted more easily,

Comment: @Clijsters Thank you for the reply. I have updated the post with the error stack trace.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I haven't setup any SSH key on my server. But I was able to access this repo earlier from my server. Where can I check the SSH key setup on my Windows SBS server and mac machine?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and couldn't find the cause. SSH worked, native git worked, jgit failed. The workaround was to use `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` - maybe jgit just doesn't like private keys with password.